# ethminer benchmarking mode llvm error

Tags: ethminer, gpu, ubuntu, linux, benchmark

I recently installed `ethminer` from the new active repository: https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer

`ethminer --version` returns:

```
ethminer version 0.11.0.dev0
Build: Linux/g++/Release
```

My OS version is **ubuntu 16.04** with kernel version **4.4.0-83-generic**.
I have an Intel Skylake graphic card, and `OpenCL 1.2` installed with `beignet 1.1.1`. `llvm 3.8-33` is also installed

When running `ethminer` in benchmarking mode (**-M** option), I faced this issue:

```
> ethminer -M -G 
[OPENCL]:Found suitable OpenCL device [Intel(R) HD Graphics Skylake ULT GT2] with 2147483648 bytes of GPU memory
Benchmarking on platform: CL
Preparing DAG for block #0
Warming up...
  ℹ  14:14:09|openclminer0  set work; seed: #00000000, target:  #000000000000
  ℹ  14:14:09|openclminer0  Initialising miner...
[OPENCL]:Using platform: Intel Gen OCL Driver
[OPENCL]:Using device: Intel(R) HD Graphics Skylake ULT GT2(OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.1.1)
ASSERTION FAILED: Not implemented
  at file /build/beignet-5qGeBM/beignet-1.1.1/backend/src/llvm/llvm_scalarize.cpp, function bool gbe::Scalarize::scalarizeExtract(llvm::ExtractElementInst*), line 722
[1]    2772 trace trap (core dumped)  ethminer -M -G
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Same issue . . .